# Is there any way to generate tornado localization CSV file like django makemessage?

Tags: python, localization, csv, internationalization, tornado

Django makemessage could generate i18n files, and make it more easier to translate.

As I see, tornado has support both CSV format and gettext format, but I can only use CSV version, because I will use it at appengine.

So, I am looking for a way to generate these CSV files for tornado base on scanning my codes and templates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I think you a bit confused. You *can* use gettext and po/mo files from within appengine, since gettext is exported from Google's django.util implementation (a discussion of this can be found in the [google-appengine google group](http://http_//groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/cf4d174c456c511/e5cb2718cb20c4e8)) :

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
```

I am not familiar with AppEngine CSV's i18n format, but there is a very easy way to extract internationalized strings from tornado's code and templates using [xgettext](http://http_//www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/gettext/xgettext-Invocation.html), just basically force python from the command line. As an example:

```
 xgettext -L Python -o myproject.pot  *.html
```

That command will get all i18n'ed strings from *.html in your current directory and will place them on myproject.pot. You can initialize that file and translate into let's say ./it_IT/myproject.po using any commercial or opensource tool (I would recommend [poedit](http://http_//www.poedit.net/) or [pootle](http://http_//translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/pootle/index?redirect=1)) and once you have translated all strings you can convert the file into CVS using [Translate Toolkit's po2csv](http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/toolkit/csv2po?redirect=1), which is also written in python:

```
po2csv -i it_IT/myproject.po -o it_IT/myproject.csv
```

The format is `location:codeLine,source,target` which is pretty simple end easy to convert to whichever other format you need (I am not familiar with appengine's i18n CSV format), you can call po2csv with no -o argument and pipe the output out from STDOUT.

I don't know if that solves your question, but basically I think you should adopt a code->pot/po->csv workflow since there are many tools that expect po/pot/mo and will allow you to handle your translations or work with translation memories/spellcheckers, etc....  try and let me know if you need any more help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a new module for the purpose called [tornado-babel](https://github.com/openlabs/tornado-babel) which includes an extractor for babel to extract translatable strings from tornado templates. It will not create the CSV file for you, but the standard pot files.